# Which model to use for multitarget classification with strong class imbalance and many categorical variables?

Tags: classification, class-imbalance, multilabel-classification

I have a small dataset 79 observations in 21 variables.
Almost all the variables are categorical variables in the format yes/no or 1/2/3.
I would like to predict jointly  three of these variables using the others.
However, I have a strong class imbalance because for the first variable just 3 out of 79 have a value equal to yes and for the second variable just 4 of 79 and among these 4, 3 are the same observation for which the first variable is yes.

Which kind of model would you use? Have you any suggestion of how to do it in Python or R? What is a good method for dealing with class imbalance without overfitting in this case?

Comment: Welcome to Data Science! You probably don’t have enough data to do much.

Comment: Yes, sadly I have to agree. Do you know if there is still something that I can try to do?